# Call syncState from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add navigation drawer to my FragmentList. 
I set custom layout with frame container, all works nice, but there is no drawer toggle icon near app icon. 
I think problem is that i do not override onPostCreate in my fragment, because, in a simple, i dont have it in fragment. But in on PostCreate i need to call toggle.SyncState.
How i can solve my problem?

Below my toggle implementation:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
            // accessibility
            R.string.hello_world // nav drawer close - description for
    // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Assigned");
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Main");
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call it in `onActivityCreated` method. This method is called in fragment just before `onPostCreate` and after `onCreate` methods in Activity.

> onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has
>   completed its own Activity.onCreate().

```
public class DrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```